# How to PIVOT data from one column into two

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a query in SQL with these results and trying to pivot them into two columns separately:

```
ID          Lat/Long     Geocoding

 1           Lat          27.4996954
 2           Lat          39.4236405
 3           Lat          40.4483913
 4           Long         -76.9341023
 5           Long         -81.0817888
 6           Long         -95.5968665
 .           .            .
 .           .            .
350          Lat          33.9760517
```

My desired results:

```
  ID         Lat          Long

   1       40.4483913     -97.303731
   .          .             .
   .          .             .
   .          .             .
 350       33.9760517      -81.0817888
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @Mark How do you match the lat and long? is it the ID?

Comment: Might your results be missing the column that pairs a latitude with a longitude? Doesn't seem to be the id?

Comment: @Mark Why the revoking of the answer? Doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

### Query

I had to make the assumption that you will pair the long and lat using the ID column.

A simple join with a where condition can solve this problem.

```
SELECT dlat.id, dlat.geocoding AS lat,
       dlong.geocoding AS lon
FROM geodata dlat inner join geodata dlong
ON  dlat.id = dlong.id     
WHERE
  dlat.latlong='lat'
  AND dlong.latlong='long';
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSzZ4YPJC3NTewoE4k7t8z/1

### DDL

```
create table geodata(
id integer,
latlong varchar(5),
geocoding float);

insert into geodata values( 1   ,   'Lat',  27.4996954  );
insert into geodata values( 2   ,   'Lat',  39.4236405  );
insert into geodata values( 3   ,   'Lat',  40.4483913  );
insert into geodata values( 4   ,   'Lat',  -76.9341023 );
insert into geodata values( 5   ,   'Lat',  -81.0817888 );
insert into geodata values( 6   ,   'Lat',  -95.5968665 );

insert into geodata values( 1   ,   'Long', 47.4996954  );
insert into geodata values( 2   ,   'Long', 59.4236405  );
insert into geodata values( 3   ,   'Long', 60.4483913  );
insert into geodata values( 4   ,   'Long', -56.9341023 );
insert into geodata values( 5   ,   'Long', -61.0817888 );
insert into geodata values( 6   ,   'Long', -75.5968665 );
```

Comment: Looking at OPs example data, the ID assumption is wrong, also seems to leave no primary key, seemingly giving no indexing on the table at all